# SQL query tutorial

Tags: sql

given that there are 2 such entities

```
city(name, country, population)
country(code, name, capital, population)
```

and the question is that there exist cities in different countries that have the same name. For instance, paris in texas, usa, and paris in france. we assume, however, that every city in one country has a unique name in that country. find the names of cities that have a unique name.

would this work then

```
SELECT DISTINCT c1.name
FROM city c1, city c2
WHERE c1.name<>c2.name;
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style should **no longer be used** and instead it is recommended to use the **proper ANSI JOIN** syntax introduced with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: To satisfy your questions requirements you will need to get counts of how many city names are used more than once. This is where an aggregate function comes in handy. Take a look at this tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Comment: Create the tables, insert some data and try different SQL constructions - that's how you learn!!!

Answer (score 1):

This will find all the cities that are unique in the database.

```
SELECT name
FROM city
Group by city
Having count(city) = 1
```

Comment: Hi @user3345791 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.